# How to get non-italic acute accent in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents, italic

`$\acute{e}$` makes an italic `e` with accent in math mode, how can I get the acute accent with a regular letter?

I should mention that this is for annotating a plot with matplotlib, so common tricks in LaTeX may not work, I tried `\text` and `\mbox`, both failed.

Comment: @PeterGrill well, apparently this is also matplotlib related though ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to do it in math mode you can use `$\acute{\mathrm{e}}$`.

Here is a comparison of the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $\acute{e}$ within math mode (without mathrm)\par
    $\acute{\mathrm{e}}$ within math mode (with mathrm)\par
    \'{e} outside of math mode
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add to the existing repertoire somewhere, `$\textrm{\'e}$ within math mode (with \verb|\textrm|)`.

Comment: @Werner Just for the record, `\textrm` seems doesn't work in my matplotlib (I didn't turn on the usetex option but leave TeX strings to python to parse).

Comment: @nye17: So `\textrm` does not work. What about `\mathrm`? Or what solution did you end up using?

Comment: @Werner peter's works, yup, `\mathrm`

Answer (score 2):

```
\'{e}
```

There's a full list of "normal" accents at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Accents#Escaped_codes

Comment: Since your answer was migrated from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), consider registering your account with this site too.